# Choose first 5 unique rows using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I currently get duplicate rows using this query:

```
List<SetInstance> RelatedSets = (from proc in dc.Processes
                                 join sip in dc.SetInstanceProcessBindingInPIs 
                                    on proc.ID equals sip.ProcessID
                                 join si in dc.SetInstances 
                                    on sip.SetInstanceID equals si.ID
                                 where proc.StationID == StationID
                                 select new SetInstanceProcess { 
                                   SI = si, 
                                   Process = proc
                                 }
                                ).Distinct()
                                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.Process.FinishDate)
                                 .Take(5).Select(x => x.SI)
                                 .ToList()
                                 .ConvertAll<SetInstance>(i => (SetInstance)i)
                                 .ToList();
```

I would like to take only a single row from the last `Process.FinishDate` and `si.ProcessID`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I tried implementing `IEqualityComparer` and overriding the equals method and using `Max` function on the `Date` parameter (both of them did not work)

Comment: What makes "rows" unique?

Comment: si.ProcessID make it unique

Comment: how about actually breaking your implementations down to more lines so people can bother understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're preforming the distinct on the `{SI, Process}` result of the query. If want only distict `SI`, try modifying the query to call the Distinct after the select. I think something like this will work:

```
List<SetInstance> RelatedSets = (from proc in dc.Processes
                             join sip in dc.SetInstanceProcessBindingInPIs 
                                on proc.ID equals sip.ProcessID
                             join si in dc.SetInstances 
                                on sip.SetInstanceID equals si.ID
                             where proc.StationID == StationID
                             select new SetInstanceProcess { 
                               SI = si, 
                               Process = proc
                             }
                            ).OrderByDescending(x => x.Process.FinishDate)
                             .Select(x => x.SI)
                             .Distinct()
                             .Take(5)
                             .ToList()
                             .ConvertAll<SetInstance>(i => (SetInstance)i)
                             .ToList();
```